# Pointer of array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I saw the following line of code in C++. I have trouble understanding it. I hope that I can get some help here.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    cout<<*a+1<<;
    cout<<a[1];

}
```

**Question**:
I don't understand how *a+1 works. It seems pretty unintuitive - are we adding 1 to the array here?

Comment: If is c++, why are you tagged [tag:c]????? Did you try to compile and launch it???

Comment: @LPs Yeah. Since I can run this both on C++ and C, I put both languages on the tag...

Comment: As far as you are able to compile it, launch it and see what is the output....BTW gcc does not compile namespaces...

Comment: This code will definitely not compile as C. C has no namespaces, doesnt know about either of those headers and doesnt have overloaded operators.

Comment: this example is as confusing as it could be. Change `{1,2,3,4}` to something like `{1,3,5,7}`, then you can run it and understand what is going on.

Comment: As it stands, it does not compile as C++ either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the expression `*a+1` you should consider the operator priority:

the dereference `*` has higher priority, so `a` (the name of an array is also the pointer to the first element) is dereferenced, giving the value `1`

Then, `1` will be added to the value.

operator priorities are describe here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `*a + 1`, the array `a` is evaluated in pointer context, so it points to the first value in the array.

Next, `*a` dereferences that pointer (meaning it gets the value the pointer points to), and that gives you the first element in the array which is `1`.

Finally, `1` is added to that value and printed, so it outputs `2`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this statement

```
cout<<*a+1<<;
          ^^^^
```

is syntactically wrong.

I think you mean something like

```
cout << *a+1 << endl;
```

Expression `*a` is equivalent to `a[0]`. So you could write instead

```
cout << a[0] + 1 << endl;
```

Take into account that semantically `a[0] + 1` is not the same as `a[1]` though applied to your example the both expressions will yield the same result.:)